# Kafka Error org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to write to a newly setup Kafka cluster on my local

`echo "Hello, World" | ~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic TutorialTopic > /dev/null`

```
[2023-08-17 02:35:07,842] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 4 on topic-partition TutorialTopic-0, retrying (2 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
.....
[2023-08-17 02:35:08,151] ERROR Error when sending message to topic TutorialTopic with key: null, value: 12 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.
....
```

I have changed the listeners value in the config.

$ cat /home/kafka/kafka/kafka.log | grep listeners

```
    advertised.listeners = null
    early.start.listeners = null
    listeners = PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

$ cat /home/kafka/kafka/kafka.log | grep 9092

```
    listeners = PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
[2023-08-17 02:34:49,791] INFO Awaiting socket connections on localhost:9092. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor)
[2023-08-17 02:34:49,974] INFO Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, czxid (broker epoch): 264 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2023-08-17 02:34:50,427] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=0 name=forwarding]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2023-08-17 02:34:50,434] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=0 name=alterPartition]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2023-08-17 02:37:37,461] WARN [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Unexpected error from /127.0.0.1 (channelId=127.0.0.1:9092-127.0.0.1:48758-1); closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

Both ports 9092 and 2181 are accessible using telnet

$ telnet localhost 9092

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
hi
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

$ telnet localhost 2181

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
ruok
imokConnection closed by foreign host.
```

$ ~/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic TutorialTopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

```
Topic: TutorialTopic    TopicId: rx7lEO7-RuOB-Uur_2lcAg PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: 
    Topic: TutorialTopic    Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `kafka-topics --create` before any producer action, otherwise, yes, there will (initially) be no leader for any non existing partition. The producer cli will retry until the topic is made...

You should realistically set `auto.topics.create=false` in a production environment

Comment: The topic has been created already.. I have put the describe command output in the question, please check.

Comment: I assume you ran that command after you started the producer code? As answered, the producer will create the topic on the first attempt, but will still print a log that it doesn't exist and retry. Try again with a brand new topic (describe before and after running your producer code)